Limits on a Staff of Flowers?
Staff of Flowers

Staff, common
This wooden staff has 10 charges. While holding it, you can use an
action to expend 1 charge from the staff and cause a flower to sprout
from a patch of earth or soil within 5 feet of you, or from the staff
itself. Unless you choose a specific kind of flower, the staff creates
a mild-scented daisy. The flower is harmless and nonmagical, and it
grows or withers as a normal flower would.
The staff regains 1d6 + 4 expended charges daily at dawn. If you
expend the last charge, roll a d20. On a 1, the staff turns into
flower petals and is lost forever.

From what I understand, this magic doesn't preclude any specific flowers. Ex: You could choose a magical and harmful flower, but the one that is created by the staff of flowers is a nonmagical and harmless.
Question:

Can you use this for a 300 GP Gilded Flower in the Summon Fey spell? (Gut reaction is no).

What is the meaning of growth? Does that imply that the staff of flower starts of as a bud?

Can you summon creatures that are of non-magical plant life? (Again, gut reaction is also a no)



Any flower that is normal and nonmagical when created is a viable target for the Awaken spell. How about a 10 foot tall corpse flower buddy? Or, if you spend the time, a squadron of them to assist in combat...

The staff creates normal flowers

You can't create a gilded flower. This creates a normal, nonmagical flower. A gilded flower is, well, gilded. Gilding is the process of covering an object in a thin layer of gold, which is not part of the flower. It also would not make sense economically if an item that has a crafting cost of 100 gp (DMG, p. 129) would be able to create multiple items worth 300 gp per day.

It creates a flower, not a bud. The default flower produced is a mild scented daisy, not a bud. The flower grows and withers as a normal flower would. For example, if you created one on a patch of earth, and tended to it, continuing to water it, and there is enough sunshine, it will continue to grow. If you don't water it, or it is in the dark underground, it will wither, as any normal flower would.

It's unlikely to create plant creatures. The text describes a mundane, normal flower as the default example. It certainly could not create a plant creature that can fight or is hazardous in any way, as the flower must be harmless. The game currently does not have any harmless plant creatures that are flowers, so they are not an option unless your DM creates one for you. So this could only work if your DM plays along, and agrees to it. The pot of awakening, another common item can create one awakened shrub every 30 days — it would be over 200 times as many creatures here if you could on average create over 7 plant creatures per day with this item.


Xanathar's Guide on Everything states in its introduction to these common magic items:

These items seldom increase a character's power, but they are likely to amuse players and provide fun roleplaying opportunities.

So think of it like that: how can you enjoy the staff to create amusing roleplaying moments; not: how you can use it for mechanical or monetary advantage.

Agreed--this staff, much like many of the other Common magic items, is basically a toy. It's not going to make you money by itself, it's not going to provide you with anything of value, it's not going to create allies for you. It's a toy. It makes flowers. Have fun with it for RP and dramatic effect.

Agreed, I understand the "RAI" argument, but was looking for something more RAW for the 1st. Also, does the game define what is harmless? Should shoving, grappling, or taking actions that indirectly cause damage mean that every creature in the game is not harmless? Anyway, thanks for the insight for 2, that was confusing me.

@Alterinam There is no formal definition of "harmless" in the rules, so you default back to the dictionary. I think anything that cause damage, directly or not, would not be harmless under such a definition.

I wouldn't rule out the bud. I would read "mild-scented daisy" as the kind of flower it creates, not the stage of development it creates the flower in. I do think it would make more sense to create a flower than a bud, but I don't see the text as precluding a bud, especially as it then specifies the flower "grows".

It would be OK if the user can decide to make only a bud — there is little to exploit.

As a concrete example regarding not being able to make money with the staff, one of the only ways to (theoretically) earn any money with it RAW would be producing saffron crocus flowers and harvesting the threads. Assuming saffron is 15 gp/lb (quoted in a number of places), you need something like 50 flowers worth of threads to earn just 1 cp, so it would take literal years for the staff to pay for itself.

15 gp per lb sounds like an insanely low price for saffron, which is running around US$10 per gram today, but on the other hand 15 gp is like $10,000 of gold IIRC, so what do I know.

@DarthPseudonym Yeah, the whole economy is really wacky though in essentially all d20 systems. Trade goods, including spices, are largely an afterthought, and often have values that make no sense when you look at things logically. For example, wheat is quoted at 1 cp/lb, which is itself hilariously cheap and suggests that commoners are likely to be spending in factional copper pieces on a regular basis.

@AustinHemmelgarn - Is it so cheap? Apparently, a lot of regular people make a few copper pieces per day doing 8 to 12 hours of hard physical labor, so they might well need to spend two copper pieces to get around 3000 calories of wheat to have enough energy to get through their day, which could be most or all of what they earn. Assuming they do not grow the wheat themselves. People earning multiples of silver and gold pieces are supposed to be rare (skilled artisans, legendary heroes), and naturally enough, they have no trouble buying a great deal of wheat.

@Obie2.0 Compared to historical wheat prices IRL in much of medieval Europe, it’s dirt cheap. Rye, barley, and oats are much easier to grow in many conditions, and made up a majority of what commoners would have used for flour on a regular basis (although oats would have meant you were really poor, since oat flour makes really hard and dense bread). Wheat, in contrast, was more expensive (at least sliver pieces per pound in D&D terms) outside of certain very limited areas, so it would have been a luxury item for a typical commoner at the time.

Well, it's a good thing Dungeons and Dragons is not set in medieval Europe, then!

@Obie2.0 My point is that there’s a strong incongruity because of things that, based on known lore, should not be significantly different from the equivalent real-world area around 1200-1500 CE, but are. Normalizing prices to ignore regional variation (for example, wheat should, no matter the base price, be far far more expensive in Icewind Dale than it is in the Greenfields) makes sense because that does make life simpler for everyone, but there’s no reason seen that the overall price of some things should be so cheap in a setting that is largely based on Europe from the Late Middle Ages.

@AustinHemmelgarn - I don't think that once you throw magic and gods and monsters in, you can make those kind of conclusions based on real-world settings.

@Obie2.0 You kind of can if you pay enough attention. For the specific case of wheat, there‘s no evidence anywhere that agricultural technology in Faerun is any better than it was IRL around the year 1500 AD. Unless we then assume that wheat is ‘different’ in this setting somehow (which is a bigger stretch by most standards than assuming that the game designers had only a vague idea what they were doing when setting up the economy), we can draw the same conclusions about relative pricing as can be drawn about places IRL from that time period.
